# how to use from snapshot in postgres replication slot?

Tags: postgresql, go, snapshot, database-replication

i am using this [package](https://github.com/jackc/pglogrepl) that it does cdc with logical slot in postgres but i want take snapshot from my database

also i read this [article](https://event-driven.io/en/how_to_get_all_messages_through_postgres_logical_replication/) But I don't know how to get the rows from snapshot

Comment: That software is woefully underdocumented. They don't say which logical decoding plugin you should be using, how you can receive the data etc. I guess you'll have to ask the authors or read and understand the code.

Comment: hi Laurenz Albe ( prophet of postgres :) , i can receive cdc with START_REPLICATION  SLOT , it s working. but i dont know that how to get snapshot data , for example , can i receive data with pg_recvlogical or START_REPLICATION  SLOT ? Should I use consistent_point ( 0/29172F0 ) or snapshot_name ( 0000000A-00000161-1 )?

Is the path I took correct?

Comment: I don't know which path you took (your question does not contain any information). You should pester the people who wrote this to provide decent documentation.

Comment: Overall, I can capture the data with Start Replication and lastXlog, but I don't know how to take a snapshot of the data

Comment: Drop this package, how can I read the snapshot using pg_recvlogical? is this possible ?  There is an article or document ?